# Python: return true if obj has exactly type t

Tags: python

given a function:

```
def my_func(obj, t)
```

My job is to write the function so that it will return true if **obj** has exactly type **t**.
It is different from isinstance. Like, isinstance always true when my_func is true, but the converse is false.

```
For example:
isinstance(True, int) = True;
myFunc(True, int) = False;
```

My code so far is:

```
def my_func(obj, t):
    return obj.__class__ == t
```

My question is that: is that right for all objects and types? if it fails, can you show me in what case it fail?(my instructor never give anything so simple)  Thanks a lot!

Comment: err huh? Not sure exactly what you are getting at here. `isinstance` is the only check you should need to make that `obj` satisfies type `t`

Comment: The code as written will actually change the class of `obj` into `t`. If you'd like to check equivalence, I'd recommend using `==`.

Comment: @KevinLondon the code is actually a syntax error, you can't assign on return

Comment: Seems to me like you have the right idea. After fixing the assignment to an equality operator, you should be good to go with that code. It's either that method or the built-in type function shown below. I'm not sure which is expected of you.

Comment: Thanks! Im afraid that it will fail somehow because my instructor always gives us something really tricky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the style of classes you are using is relevant here. Python 3 uses new-style classes and Python 2 is capable of old-style classes and new-style classes. Some relevant expressions in the Python 2 interpreter are shown below:

```
>>> class A: pass; # old-style class (default style in py2)
...
>>> class B(object): pass; # new-style class (default style in py3)
...
>>> type(A())
<type 'instance'>
>>> A().__class__
<class __main__.A at 0x01DC97A0>
>>> type(B())
<class '__main__.B'>
>>> B().__class__
<class '__main__.B'>
```

The key point to note here is that for new-style classes, using `.__class__` is indeed equivalent to built-in `type` function, but for old-style classes, `type(A()) != A().__class__`. This is because `A().__class__ == A` is `True` while `type(A()) == A` is `False` for old-style classes.

If you are using Python 2, I would recommend using `.__class__` instead of `type()` so you can handle custom-made types. If you are using Python 3, you can go with either method, since new-style classes are the default there.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`type` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) from Python to check. It will only return `True` if the class has exactly the same type as `t`.

```
def my_func(obj, t):
    return type(obj) == t
```

Comment: The goal, according to the question, is only to return True when it's has exactly the type of t.

Comment: It will also fail for instances, `class T(): pass; type(T()) == T`

Comment: Yes, that's true. As with the docs, I would normally recommend `isinstance()` for equivalence checking.

Comment: so what is the differences between obj.__class__ and type(obj)? I thought they are the same, arent they?